# Magento sub / extending theme local.xml structure

Tags: magento

I've a Magento store running with a self-made default theme according to the rules from the Magento Designer Guide. So my /default/default/ theme has its own local.xml file.

Now I want to add a new theme /default/extendingtheme/ . Extendingtheme is a theme that has to extend my original theme and has only some slightly differences compared to the default theme. So it would use 95% of the default theme's local.xml .

Unfortunately I have to create a new local.xml file for my 'extendingtheme' duplicating all the content of the default theme, which isn't efficient. Isn't there a way including the 95% of the default local.xml file in my new extendingtheme's local.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it will always take the nearest local.xml it could take. You could create another xml file, like extensiontheme.xml and then include to layout update from your extension config.xml:

```
<frontend>
<layout>
    <updates>
        <extensiontheme>
            <file>extensiontheme.xml</file>
        </extensiontheme>
    </updates>
</layout>
</frontend>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I guess this is for Magento extensions/plugins? My question is just about the template designing part and doesn't have to do anything with extensions.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know any other way to include your custom xml file, but it seems to be okay in magento world to create extension for theme. If you would need to add some setting related to theme to backend or create/override some magento classes for your theme you could use your extension for this too.